Flexbox and max-width? Parent width is max-width when child is less wide


.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Centers items vertically */
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}

.column {
    max-width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<div class="row">
        <div class="column">Text</div>
</div>



Inside a flex box element I have a div with a max-width. Inside the div will be headings. Some headings are long, some short. Even with short headings I want the div to expand to the max-width (not shrink to the width of the child element). Is this possible without using breakpoints?
I've tried various combinations of max-width combined with width and min-width, but can't get it to work
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.column {
  max-width: 90rem;
  background-colour: red;
}



<div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>


Why not just use width?

"Even with short headings I want the div to expand to the max-width" - Did you mean to use min-width?  Though it's worth noting that the width in the code snippet is indeed 900px for me in Chrome, at least when my viewport is wider than that.

I've discovered that the max-width is not working because it is inside a flex box item.

@user2991837: max-width means that's the maximum width, so the element can't grow larger than that.  You want min-width to set a minimum width for the element.  (Essentially a typo?)

No typo. Flex makes the element shrink to fit its content by default. See code snippet

@user2991837: And in that code snippet, what happens when you replace max-width with min-width?

I don't want a min-width.

You have to maintain the hierarchy while targeting the child element.


.row {
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center; /* Centers items vertically */
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>



Also, flex-grow: 1 will result in same output.

It's because you use
Flex-grow:1;,by using flex-grow only, its basis tends to be auto, for a flex item that has auto as its basis, it normally takes the width of the content in it. So advisely you use
Flex-flow:1; then your max-width
